# Very weird behaviour when running the same deep learning code in two different GPUs

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I am training networks using pytorch framework. I had K40 GPU in my computer. Last week, I added 1080 to the same computer.

In my first experiment, I observed identical results in both GPU. Then, I tried my second code on both GPUs. In this case, I "constantly" got good results in K40 while getting "constantly" awful results in 1080 for "exactly the same code".

First, I thought the only reason for getting such diverse outputs would be the random seeds in the codes. So, I fixed the seeds like this:

```
torch.manual_seed(3)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(3)
numpy.random.seed(3)
```

But, this did not solve the issue. I believe issue cannot be randomness because I was "constantly" getting good results in K40 and "constantly" getting bad results in 1080. Moreover, I tried exactly the same code in 2 other computers and 4 other 1080 GPUs and always achieved good results. So, problem has to be about the 1080 I recently plugged in.

I suspect problem might be about driver, or the way I installed pytorch. But, it is still weird that I only get bad results for "some" of the experiments. For the other experiments, I had the identical results.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Problem seems to be solved after re-installing pytorch!

Answer (score 1):

Q: can you please tell what type of experiment this is.. and what architecture of NN you use ?

In below tips, I will assume you are running a straight backpropagation neural net.

- You say learning of your test experiment is "unstable" ? Training of a NN should *not* be "unstable". When it is, different processors could end up with a different outcome, influenced by numeric precision and rounding errors. *Saturation* could have occurred.. Check if your weight values have become too large. In that case 1) check if your training input and output are logically consistent, and 2) add more neurons in hidden layers and train again.
- Good idea to check random() calls, but take into account that in a backprop NN  there are several places random() functions can be used. Some backprop NN's also add dynamic noise to training patterns, to prevent early saturation of weights.  When this training noise is scaled wrong, you could get bizarre results. When the noise is not added or too small, you could end up with saturation.

Comment: Training is very instable. You're optimizing over a very high dimensional surface. Hitting a ridge (in any dimension) can cause one training run to go one way, and another run can go to the other side of the ridge. This can be caused by something as simple as fusing or not fusing a multiply-add.

Comment: "Stability" term is probably confusing, it is my fault. The only thing you should keep in mind is that I am constantly getting good results in K40 and "1080s" in other computers. But, I constantly get bad results for 1080 I recently plugged in. The problem cannot be about randomness, input-output consistency or network structure. Because I am consistently getting good results in all the other GPUs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share my code. But, the code that works in both GPUs uses ResNet while the one it does not work for my new GPU uses a large convolutional network. Again, problem has to be about my new GPU as the same code works in everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by simply changing

> sum

to

> torch.sum

. Please try to change all the build-in functions to GPU one.

Comment: But why does it behave like that?